# Using 'having' in CodeIgniter's Active Record

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord, syntax

Does anyone know why this syntax doesn't work / causes a server error?

```
    $this->db->having('post_timestamp >=' . strtotime('last saturday'));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using MySQL the query might be escaped. Try this:

```
$this->db->having('post_timestamp >='. strtotime('last saturday'), NULL, FALSE);
```